# Debian: set desktop resolution for non-monitor box

Tags: debian, display, kde-4, debian-wheezy

I have a debian box running Wheezy and booting into KDE4. The computer doesn't have any monitor attached but is set to start a vnc server for remote connection when main user auto-logins on startup. The problem is that when i connect to the vnc server the resolution is messed up (something like 480x320). How can i set the desktop resolution?

Comment: What VNC server?  AFAIK there are at least 3 different VNC servers in the repository.

Comment: x11vnc. The problem is not with setting the vnc server 'geometry' parameter. The problem is that the desktop screen is too small.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.
I had to modify my video card's modprobe file to:
`options radeon modeset=0`
and then add my own xorg conf file to specify the monitor details.
I created the custom conf file in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/` and added only monitor parameters like:

```
Section "Device"
Identifier "VNC Device"
Driver "vesa"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
Identifier "VNC Screen"
Device "VNC Device"
Monitor "VNC Monitor"
SubSection "Display"
Modes "1600x900"
EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
Identifier "VNC Monitor"
HorizSync 30-70
VertRefresh 50-75
EndSection
```